# python else statement confusion

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python programming. I am a little confused in the below code, how else statements work without corresponding if statement. Could anyone please explain to me the below code. Program is Prime number between two intervel.

```
start=int(input("Enter Number: "))
    stop=int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
    
    for i in range(start,stop):
        if i>1:
            for j in range(2,i//2+1):
                if(i%j==0):
                    break
            
    
            else:
                print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, [loops can have an `else` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). However, think more of a try-except statement than a if clause.

An example:

```
for item in container:
    if search_something(item):
        # Found it!
        break
else:
    # Didn't find anything..
```

Comment: `for-else` has nothing to do with the emptiness of what you are iterating over. The `else` triggers if the `break` is never reached.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear answer. But for-else is the answer to the question I think (namely why there is a else without an if).

Comment: Yup, of course, hence the duplicate question. But any answer should mention the all important relation between the `break` and the `else`.